# MS Access UniqueIdentifier #deleted

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to update some records in Ms Access, I have some linked views to SQL but when I try and view the table in access with the primary key it shows some records as #deleted but if I join it without the primary key it shows all records. The primary key is UniqueIdentifier (newid()). The issue is that I need the primary key so that I can run my update query. Update Query is

```
UPDATE  vw_A LEFT JOIN vw_B ON vw_A.ID = vw_B.ID SET vw_A.reviewed = vw_B.Reviewed
WHERE vw_A.id=vw_B.id;
```

vw_B table has #deleted in some rows which I think is because of the GUID. if I try and update this without the primary key I get the  Operation must use an updateable query. Do I need to create a table for vw_B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way of doing this but I just created 3 query's which is my work around

```
SELECT * INTO vwb_Dup FROM vw_b;

ALTER TABLE vwb_Dup ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)

UPDATE vw_A LEFT JOIN vwb_Dup  ON vw_A.ID = vwb_Dup.ID SET vw_A.reviewed = vwb_Dup.Reviewed WHERE vw_A.id=vwb_Dup.id;
```